# Read a single user input using scanf and convert it into appropriate data type

Tags: c, input

I have a program that reads user input as such:

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);
```

and then checks if it is a digit:

```
if(isdigit(c)) {
    int f = atoi(c);
    return f;
}

switch(c) {
    case 'q':
        exit(1);
        break;
    ...
}
...
```

Example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    scanf("%c", &c);

    if(isdigit(c)) {
        int f = atoi(&c);
        printf("f: %d\n", f);
        return f;
    }

    switch(c) {
        case 'q':
            printf("q\n");
            return -1;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However when I enter, for exmaple, 10 then the input becomes 1 and 0 and \n. I want 10. How do I read "10" and "100" and "4" for example as well as other characters such as "q"?

Comment: You can read a string

Comment: Remember that the argument to `atoi` is a null-terminated string. It also have no kind of validation. Use e.g. [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) for a conversion function with validation.

Comment: @ForceBru if I read a string, then how do I both convert it into a float and use a switch statement?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the reminder. I am just starting to learn C and I know the down fall of scanf and atoi, etc. This is just to get started. Thanks again!

Comment: @pointersarehard, you can use `strcmp` instead of the `switch` statement

Comment: @ForceBru using scanf for a string: `char string[200];` results in `format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'char (*)[256]' [-Wformat]`

Comment: @pointersarehard, try reading into `&string[0]` instead of `string`.

Comment: Use plain `string` and not `&string`. Or `&string[0]` (which is what plain `string` will *decay* to).

Comment: Now I am unable to use "isdigit" because it cannot take in a char array: `warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing
      'char [10]' to parameter of type 'int'`

Comment: First read your string. Then check if it's the "quit" command. Then try to convert it to an integer. And if the conversion succeeded (and the whole string was converted) then use the integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char variables are only capable of saving one character. So if you want to have multiple characters (numbers are also characters) in a char variable you have to use `string` or `char VARIABLE[size]` . For example: `char variable[10]` can save up to 10 characters. But then you can't use `isdigit()` in that way anymore. Instead you have to use a loop to check each character of the string.